# Click Once Deployment for Mac

Tags: macos, clickonce, osx-lion

As the title states, is there an equivalent to Click Once application deployment for the Mac?

I ask this because the version of Safari that ships with Lion has removed DMG (disk image) files as a "safe file type" that is opened after downloading.  The company I work for has a rather special-purpose application that should launch as soon as it is downloaded.

Comment: Could you describe this "rather special-purpose" application? Because I'm struggling to think of a situation where I'd want this to happen on my Mac.

Comment: So, why can't you use the Mac App Store (http://www.apple.com/mac/app-store/)?  It's a form of web deployment available for Macs.  You may not control the distribution channels, but if your use to use Apple hardware, you're probably use to those types of limitations.

Comment: It's sad that all four of your comments are just snide remarks.  I thought StackOverflow was a place where people came to ask and answer questions, not a place puff up your chest and act like a child.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this?  [I have a very specific case for which this is necessary here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12080447/mac-launch-desktop-application-from-browser-passing-parameters)

Comment: possible duplicate of [is it possible to run clickonce application with Mono?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20274138/is-it-possible-to-run-clickonce-application-with-mono)

Comment: @huntharo No, this is not a duplicate because the application in question was written using native Objective-C, not Mono.

Comment: @Paul - Nope, still seems like a duplicate.  The answer applies to both questions... it wouldn't be right to post the answer to that question here... it'd just be stealing points.  The title of the other question could be cleaned up to say "built with Mono or Native".  The answer (Squirrel) doesn't care if you built the app with Mono or not... it doesn't know anything about Mono.

Comment: @huntharo Squirrel doesn't not provide a method for deploying the initial app on Mac; only updates once the app has been launched. ClickOnce does both which was why I originally asked "launch as soon as it is downloaded". This is not a duplicate.