# is it possible to run clickonce application with Mono?

Tags: c#-4.0, mono, clickonce

i'm developing clickonce application which, potentially, i would like to distribute on Mac platform. I know i can compile .Net application wtih Mono - and it will work on Mac. But can I use clickonce as the installer then?

thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I don't think Mono team has ever implemented the ClickOnce .NET APIs that make this possible. However, I think it should be kind of straightforward to implement them.

That being said, it might be wiser to just use the Mac backend for [Squirrel](https://github.com/Squirrel/). (Which is a project implemented by Github employees, used in their Github Windows client, that replaces/improves ClickOnce, as far as I know.)

Comment: thanks for the link - i will definitely review it! thanks again.

Comment: @knocte - do you know any other projects which use Squirrel? how mature is that? because from what I see there, i really like it..

Comment: it's kind of unmature, but the guy that implemented it used to work at Microsoft, so I don't think that there's any risk adopting it